# How can I load a template of a view within another view in a component?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to add a view that I made (a table) to another view that I need to appear again. How can I do this? Actually I am trying to add a view within another view using theloadtemplate function.

This is what I type inside the view, but it does't seem to work, can anyone help?
The message I get is the following

> Layout default_reports not found

```
<div>
     <?php $jinput =  JFactory::getApplication()->input;
           $jinput->set('view', 'reports');
           echo $this->loadTemplate("reports");
           $jinput->set('view', 'master');?>
</div>
```

But the view is there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `loadTemplate` function, we call only the layout inside the view.

We concatenate two or more layout using the loadtemplate inside the following view.

By default joomla, it call the layout by a prefix as `default_`. So we have to create a layout as reports means filename as `default_reports.php` but we need to call the layout as you have mentioned

```
echo $this->loadTemplate("reports");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to load "layouts" from another "view" in the current `view.html.php` file, then you can do so as below.

```
$this->addTemplatePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'views' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'anotherview' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmpl');
$this->setLayout('layoutfromanotherview');
```